# Sharetribe marketplace Fresh install error -> No address associated with hostname

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sharetribe

I’ve been following [a blog post](https://sangram.hashnode.dev/self-hosted-sharetribe-go-community-edition-on-ubuntu) to get a single standalone [Sharetribe](https://github.com/sharetribe/sharetribe) marketplace up at my domain theasign [dot] com.

I’ve managed to get things working up to the last step, which is to get the app to load at my url. I get a 500 Internal Server Error.

I don’t need a subdomain but I’m confused as to if this is mandatory? I get the error below.

```
RuntimeError (No address associated with hostname):
app/utils/current_marketplace_resolver.rb:27:in sole_community_or' app/utils/current_marketplace_resolver.rb:5:in resolve_from_host’
lib/rack_middleware/marketplace_lookup.rb:13:in call' lib/rack_middleware/custom_cookie_renamer.rb:11:in call’
lib/rack_middleware/enforce_ssl.rb:23:in call' lib/rack_middleware/health_check.rb:12:in call
```

I suspect it has something to do with [these instructions](https://github.com/sharetribe/sharetribe#setting-your-domain). Are these necessary and how do you go about doing it? and what the hell is the “ident” field in the community model?

Comment: Did you follow [setting up your domain](https://github.com/sharetribe/sharetribe#setting-your-domain)? It is very difficult to tell what is going on from your current post other than `Community.count` fails.

Comment: @engineersmnky Thanks for the comment. I guess that's my question, I'm not sure what the "setting up your domain" instructions mean when they say: "In your database, change the value of the domain column in the communities table to match the hostname of your domain. "

I've created a record in the communities table with the following attributes:
ident: "the-a-sign",                                                     
 domain: "www.theasign.com",                                              
 use_domain: true,